# Getting CATCH_SINGLE_INCLUDE: command not found Error, when i am compiling the 010-TestCase.cpp file in Catch2

Tags: c++11, g++, catch2

I am geetting this error while compiling the 010-TestCase.cpp file which is in examples in catch2. I am very new to this framework. Please respond if anyone have opinion about this.Cat

Comment: Please share how you invoke the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be issue when using examples with single-header distribution of Catch2 as an opposite to CMake installation.

What did the trick for me was removing offending `-I$(CATCH_SINGLE_INCLUDE)` from the example command. It didn't appear in Google Search but I expect it to contain path to  which I do include barely as "catch2.hpp".

Test works for me after I've eended up with:

`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o 010-TestCase 010-TestCase.cpp && ./010-TestCase --success`

Comment: You could end in `fatal error: catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp: No such file or directory` in this way

Comment: It was three years ago. I’d recommend opening a ticket on GitHub now.